# Powershellでフォルダ内のファイル削除を実施時に、特定のフォルダだけ除外したい

Tags: powershell

表題の通りですが、以下のような感じで特定のフォルダだけ削除を実施したくないのですが
上手くいきません。

なにか方法はないでしょうか？

```
$filePath = 'C:\temp\'　 # 削除対象フォルダ
$excludeItem = '処理済'　# 削除対象内で除外したいフォルダ

Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Exclude $excludeItem -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)} | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Comment: 解決したいはずの肝心なことが書かれていません。「上手くいきません」とのことですが、どの辺りが期待と異なるのでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました
解決したいのは除外したいフォルダの指定で、「処理済」というフォルダは何が入っていても削除対象外としたいのですが、excludeはファイル指定はできてもフォルダ指定ができないようで、、
tempフォルダ内はサブフォルダも含め、基本は削除する、ただし処理済というサブフォルダだけは対象外にしたが、うまくいかないという内容です。

Comment: ちなみに`処理済`フォルダを最初から`C:\temp`の下ではなく別の所に作るとか、一時的に別の場所に移動しておいて、他を削除した後に戻すとかでは駄目なのでしょうか？

Comment: 「除外したいフォルダ」の下にあるファイルの扱いは、「一緒に残す」「除外フォルダ自体が残ればよい (配下のファイルは削除」のどちらを想定していますか？

Comment: 移動は検討してみますが、仮でtempとしていますが本番ではサブフォルダがどの程度作成されるかも未定で、どのサブフォルダに作成しても「処理済」とう名称であれｂ残すという形にしたいです。

除外フォルダの下にあるファイルは、一緒に残すと考えています。

Answer (score 1):

下記のスクリプトでできます。

```
ls -Path $filePath -Recurse | ?{if($_.PSIsContainer){$_.Name -ne $excludeItem -and (ls $_.FullName -Directory -Filter $excludeItem).Count -eq 0}else{$_.FullName -notmatch $excludeItem}} | rm -Recurse  -Force -WhatIf
```

**解説**

ご質問の通りフォルダの`-Exclude`はできないので、とりあえず全ファイルを再帰的に取得します。

```
ls -Path $filePath -Recurse
```

単純に次のWhere-Object(エイリアスは`?{}`)でできそうと思いますが、サブフォルダの`$excludeItem`を考慮してくれません。
つまり`C:\temp\hoge\処理済\`が存在する場合でも、`C:\temp\hoge\`を削除しようとするためNGです。

```
ls -Path $filePath -Recurse | ?{ $_.fullname -notmatch $excludeItem }
```

これを回避するために、Where-Objectの中でフォルダとファイルに対する処理を分けました。

```
?{
    if($_.PSIsContainer){
        # フォルダの場合、フォルダ名が $excludeItem ではない、かつ子フォルダに $excludeItem が一つも存在しない
        $_.Name -ne $excludeItem -and
        (ls $_.FullName -Directory -Filter $excludeItem).Count -eq 0
    }else{
        # ファイルの場合、フルパスに $excludeItem を含まない
        $_.FullName -notmatch $excludeItem
    }
}
```

後は該当のファイルフォルダを削除します。(もちろん`-WhatIf`オプションがあるので実際には消えません)

```
 | rm -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Comment: Where-Objectの使い方ですが、テストしてみて上手く実行できました。
ありがとうござます。助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

質問の内容を整理すると、

```
$filePath = 'C:\temp\'　 # 削除対象フォルダ
$excludeItem = '処理済'　# 削除対象内で除外したいフォルダ
```

を前提に

- `$filePath` 配下を再帰的に削除を行いたい
- ただし、`$filePath` 直下にある `$excludeItem` 配下は削除から除外したい

でしょうか。

[`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) の `-Exclude` は 除外する名前を指定するもので、例えば `*.txt` は削除しない、など個々のファイル名に対する除外指定に使えます。今回のように特定のディレクトリ以下全てを除外する機能は持ちません。

---

「`$filePath` 配下を再帰的に削除」という発想を転換して

- `$filePath` 直下のディレクトリ（ただし`$excludeItem`を除く）を再帰的に削除
- `$filePath` 直下のファイルを削除

と分けて考えれば、シンプルな記述ができそうです。具体的には

```
Get-ChildItem $filePath -Directory -Exclude $excludeItem | Remove-Item -Recurse
Get-ChildItem $filePath -File | Remove-Item
```

でどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ディレクトリ自体は削除したくないのですが、参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: @真夜中 コメントでも指摘しましたが、何を実行したいかもう少しわかりやすく質問文に記載してください。今からでも編集していただけるとより正確な回答をできます。